# I am unable to execute select query using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, azure, select

I am trying to fetch records form postgres using below query but it is not working.

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="xxx",
    database="yyy",
    user="aaa",
    port="5432",
    password="bbb")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from table_name")
cur.fetchall()
```

I get the error Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL relation "table_name" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from table_name
^

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: If you are sure the table exists, you might be connecting to the wrong database on your instance, or the wrong instance entirely, where the table does not exist. The table could also be in a non-public schema - if so, you need to refer to it as `schema_name.table_name`. Or, it could be a typo that we don't see if you altered the name of your table when you asked the question.

Comment: I can the see the table within the schema. The same query works in postgres  admin tool

Comment: @Coder Are sure you're inspecting the same database on the same instance in your PGAdmin? Are your PGAdmin connection settings the same as the ones in your psycopg2 connection string? Checked for typos in table_name compared to its name on the db? Can you show use the query you created the table with?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You need to create a Table in your database and then you can query it.

To create a table:

> cur.execute("CREATE TABLE table_name")

Now, you can execute your queries

> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")